# Is there anyway of restoring permissions to default in SalesCloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, permissions, permission-sets, marketing-cloud-connect

After configuring MC Connect, I've been messing around with the permissions and now I can't see certain layouts and I don't know what I changed.

Can I restore somehow the permissions to default?

Thanks!

Comment: Do toy have a sandbox or a source control where these permissions are in a pristine state?

Comment: Yes, I do have it. Is there anyway to get them from there? Would reconnect and connect again work?